# I am trying to DIY outdoor gazebo solar lights

Tags: solar-energy, lighting

Im no electrical engineer. Just a bored ADHD mum trying to make her home nice and eco friendly.
So we just set up a gazebo tent un our courtyard and it gets really dark at night. We dont have any external plugs and i dont want to run a lead out from inside because we have a toddler and want to be safe.

I was thinking of buying some LED bulbs and a bulb socket hanging cord (like for pendant lights) but im trying to make it Solar rechargeable.

I found some E27 sockets with USB and im not sure what type of solar panel and controller i need to get.

The bulbs will be 60 watts. Smart bulbs with color changing and speakrr functions.

Was thinking of hooking the controller up to a 20,000 mah 60watt power bank. Will this work if i connect it on the controller usb port? I only need 3 to 4 hours of light usage (less or none some days).

Any ideas or advice would be lovely!

Comment: Need specs. Probably your 60 W lights aren't. But instead rated as providing the kind of illuminance that a 60 W incandescent would. If so, they are really only 10 W (likely.) Assuming the power bank is providing 5 V, this means 10 lamp-hours. (10 hours with 1 lamp, 5 hours with 2 lamps, 2 hours with 5 lamps, etc.) But we need to see specifications for the lights and the power bank's total deliverable Joules (which they likely won't tell us... but we can hope.)

Comment: You can also try this solar bottle lamp. Solar Bottle Lamp is a solar-powered light that is constructed from waste plastic bottles. The design idea is to reuse waste plastic bottles : https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/DIY_Solar_Bottle_Lamp_05a5334b.html

Comment: Since you asked in the electrical engineering forum and not the home improvement forum I would put together my own little off-grid system with a battery, solar panel, and lights. It would be an excellent starter project if you want to work with electricity more in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my answer is applicable to your situation, but here's how I'd approach making the system myself. You *did* ask in the electrical engineering forum and not the [home improvement forum](https://diy.stackexchange.com) after all :)

If you want to learn about electricity, I think putting together this system is an *excellent* starter project. It will cost approximately $100-$200.

Disclaimer: I'm some random person on the internet. I am not a professional electrical engineer but I did build something like this in my spare time. Although I've written a lot in this answer, there is not excruciating detail and this is not a tutorial on how to solder, use a crimp tool, or strip wires. I may have made some mistakes which someone else will correct. And I don't know squat about building codes.

---

**Overview:** You will make a separate 12-volt power system with a battery, a solar panel, and 12-volt lights. A charge controller will protect the battery from being over-charged or under-charged. A switch will turn the lights on and off.

**Connections:** When choosing parts pay attention to how the wires can be connected as you'll have to actually connect them. There are spade terminals, little sticking out metal tabs which slot into corresponding connectors that you can crimp onto wires. But you need the crimp tool (mine was about $30). If you don't want to buy the tool you can look for parts with screw connections instead. Charge controllers and solar panels often have screws. Batteries are likely to not come with screws, but rather come with holes that you can put your own screws through. LED strips are solderable; they may come with connectors attached. If something comes with a wire, you can always cut the wire and then you have a bare wire end. To connect a wire end you have to remove (strip) some insulation to expose the actual metal wire inside. This can be done with a wire stripping tool, or with scissors and patience.

At some point you'll probably need to join two bare wire ends. You can do this by soldering (remember to put heat-shrink tube over the joint for insulation), or with by crimping a [butt connector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrpgeTqANKk) over both ends, or with a [WAGO connector](https://www.amazon.com/wago-connectors/s?k=wago+connectors), wire nuts, etc. Personally I'm a fan of soldering or butt connectors as they are quite versatile.

AWG 18 / 0.75mm^2 is a good wire size. It is for at least 10 amps and probably more. It is conventional to use red wires for positive and black wires for negative, so that you won't accidentally mix them up, but the electrons don't care what colour the wire is. Sometimes you can find red and black wires together in a bundle.

**Safety note:** 12 volts is safe to touch. There is no electrocution danger at all. However, short-circuiting a lead-acid battery causes it to discharge quickly, producing a high amounts of current (amps) that can make sparks and [burn and melt wires](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/LxtTSzr9DJw). Short-circuiting a solar panel of this size is usually not dangerous although you might get a little spark.

Since this is outdoors, make sure electrical parts are safe from water, even in in very bad storms. That doesn't mean you have to go overboard - the insulation on wires protect them from moderately heavy rain, and you can get lighting strips with a kind of plastic coating that does the same - just make sure water doesn't build up there. Connection points are more vulnerable. Also consider that things on the ground might be impacted by metal objects blown around by strong winds. You wouldn't want to start a fire because someone littered a sheet of aluminium foil and a strong wind happened to blow it perfectly against your battery terminals.

Soldering irons are hot. Don't touch the metal part until they cool down. Don't leave the metal part touching a flammable surface. Usually they come with stands to put them in.

Don't run with scissors.

---

**Lighting:** Instead of E27 bulbs, I recommend LED lighting strips ([example](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Dimmable-Self-Adhesive-Flexible-Controller-Included/dp/B07TJXZNDZ), ignore the power adapter, you will not need it). The lights come in different lengths, different colours, many have a water-resistant coating, many have adhesive backing - take your pick. You can even get RGB ones where you can change the colour by remote control, but I won't explain how to wire those. Make sure they say 12V.

All types of LED strips can be cut and joined at certain intervals (e.g. every 6-10 cm, marked with a line). If you buy a 5m reel you can cut it up into 5 times 1m or whatever length you like. They only come with connectors attached at the end of the reel, so at the cut points you have to solder your own, which isn't difficult, but it requires a soldering iron and solder. If you don't cut them, you don't need to solder.

Use as much as you want to. You can make it into shapes, etc. Great stuff.

We'll do the energy calculations with amps because it's more convenient. The lighting probably tells you how many watts it uses per meter (or per foot). Divide by 12 to get amps. You should use a few I predict you'll only need a few - need less than 5 and certainly less than 10.

Note that although LED lightbulbs come in "fake incandescent watts", LED strips are rated according to the power they *actually* use. A "60 watt" lightbulb is more like 10 watts and the equivalent amount of strip lighting will say 10 watts.

You could use the power adapter (if it came with one) to test the brightness before setting up the solar power stuff.

---

**Battery:** The type of battery may be variously labeled as AGM, gel, SLA, sealed lead-acid, or maintenance-free lead-acid. Make sure it says 12V. There is some small difference between AGM and gel but they are basically interchangeable. [Example in German language](https://www.battery-direct.de/12v-12ah-akku-bp12-12.html).

Be warned, these batteries are heavy because they are literally made of lead. But the advantage of this type is they're several times cheaper than lithium batteries. They're also about 98% recyclable. (Make sure to recycle them when they eventually wear out. Filling landfills with lead is no bueno)

I wrote about choosing the battery size below.

**Fuse:** Because the battery can produce a high current, you want a fuse in line with the battery, as close to the battery as possible. It doesn't matter whether it's in the positive or negative wire. My system has an "inline car fuse holder" [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081DHT8Y7) and inside the holder goes a car fuse.

The purpose of a fuse is to be a weak link. If there's a short circuit that causes a lot of electricity to flow, the fuse breaks before anything else breaks. You find the problem, you fix the problem, and then you replace the burnt fuse.

It should be as close to the battery as possible, so that all of the wiring is protected. The wiring between the fuse and the battery is not protected.

Connect the battery or insert the fuse *last*, so that if you make a short circuit while you are building everything else, it doesn't do anything.

---

**Solar panel:**

Make sure it's marketed as 12V on the brochure. If you look at the technical specifications the "open circuit voltage" will be more like 18V or 20V. That's okay as it will drop down to 12V when it's charging the battery.

If you have an MPPT charge controller (see below), on a bright sunny day you get power according to the number of watts (divide by 12 for amps). If you don't have one, you get power according to the "short circuit amps", and that will probably be quite a bit less - 30-40% less.

I wrote about choosing the solar panel size below.

---

**How big?**

The eternal question of solar power systems. How big of a battery do you need, and how big of a solar panel? There is no perfect answer.

Remember how it works: When you turn the lights on, the power comes out of the battery. Therefore the battery must be big enough to power all the lights you want, for as long as you want. When the sun is shining, the solar panel makes power and recharges the battery. Therefore the solar panel must be big enough to recharge the power you used from the battery.

Battery size is measured in Ah, or amp-hours. 1 amp x 1 hour = 1 amp-hour. 0.5 amps x 2 hours = 1 amp-hour.

So if your LED lights take 2 amps and you need it to last for 4 hours that's 8 amp-hours. But maybe we suppose you might get 2 days without sunlight in a row (3 nights in a row), so make it 24 amp-hours. And maybe we say there are 9 good sunlight hours in the day, so you need 3 amps of charging power to recharge the whole battery in 1 day.

But this is all very rough; you do get some power on cloudy days, you won't use it for 4 hours every day; you don't always get 9 hours of sunlight, especially in winter. Just make it bigger than you think you need and you won't run out of power. Or heck, if you want to, make it small, and then you can experiment to see how long it actually lasts. You **can** upgrade later by adding on more solar panels or more batteries.

---

**Charge controller:**

You **can** directly wire together a battery, solar panel and lights and call it a day. However, if you leave it unattended, the battery is likely to get damaged from overcharging or over-discharging. Have you ever left the headlights on at night in your car? If the battery is completely dead in the morning, it's ruined and you need a new one - you can't just recharge it. Slow overcharging is less bad, but it can make the battery wear out faster.

So you want a *charge controller* ([examples](https://www.amazon.de/solar-charge-controller-12v/s?k=solar+charge+controller+12v)). This little box sits between the battery, the solar panel, and the lights, and it watches the charge level. If the battery is full, it cuts off the solar panel, and if the battery is empty, it cuts off the lights. Then you can leave it unattended without fear.

Like the rest of the parts, these come in a wide variety. Make sure you get one designed for 12V, not lithium batteries (they should say if for lithium, the rest aren't), and the amp rating should be higher than you need. With those restrictions in mind, the very cheapest one probably works fine. You're free to upgrade if you want to - if you want to use a Bluetooth app, or you want one with USB ports to charge your phone in the gazebo, or whatever, you can. MPPT is a special feature that sucks more power out of the solar panel, but it costs more. You can get it if you want to. PWM means "not MPPT".

---

**Building code and insurance requirements:** I have literally no idea. You should probably find out before you build it permanently.